# Question about termwise differentation of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_{k}\left(x\right)\in C^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ bounded functions and assume that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|f_{k}\left(x\right)\right|<+\infty$$ and $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|f_{k}^{\prime}\left(x\right)\right|<+\infty.$$ Can I conclude that $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f_{k}\left(x\right)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f_{k}^{\prime}\left(x\right)?\tag{1}$$ I know that if $f_{k}\left(x\right)$ converges pointwise and $f_{k}^{\prime}\left(x\right)$ converges uniformly, then $(1)$ holds but I'm not able to verify the the uniform convergence of the series of derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the dominated convergence theorem to the series of derivatives.

By the premises, $g(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \lvert f_k'(x)\rvert$ is a bounded function. As the sum of a series of nonnegative continuous functions, $g$ is lower semicontinuous. Hence $g$ is locally integrable, and dominates $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} f_k'(x)$. By the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\int_x^y \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} f_k'(t)\,dt = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \int_x^y f_k'(t)\,dt = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigl(f_k(y) - f_k(x)\bigr) = \Biggl(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f_k(y)\Biggr) - \Biggl(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f_k(x)\Biggr).$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\sum f_k$ is continuously differentiable with $\bigl(\sum f_k\bigr)' = \sum f_k'$.

Comment: Just the last question. "As the sum of a series of nonnegative continuous functions, $g$ is lower semicontinuous". Where can I find a reference of it?

Comment: The first reference that fell into my hands was part (c) of section 2.8 in Rudin's _Real and Complex Analysis_, "The supremum of any collection of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous." Here, the partial sums are continuous, hence lower semicontinuous, and by nonnegativity, the total sum is the supremum of the partial sums.